# Removing quotes from elements in python list

Tags: python, list

I have a python list that looks like `alist = ['4', '1.6', 'na', '2e-6', '42']`. If i want to remove the quotes from this and make it look like `[4, 1.6, na, 2e-6, 42]`, normally i use the following code :

```
alist = [float(x) if type(x) is str else None for x in alist]
```

But this time, as I have the string `'na'` as one of the elements in the list, this line of code will not work. Is there an elegant way to do this in python?

Comment: You mean `nan` instead of `na`?

Comment: for some reason i have many big lists, and whenever there is no value, it says na or no, instead of nan.

i want to know if it is possible to do for any letters!

Comment: What do you expect an algorithm to produce if the list contains `'na'`?

Comment: Btw, you say "this line of code will not work", but you should be more specific, that is you should tell us exactly why it's not working. Maybe some of us can immediately recognize the problem or try to run your code, but you shouldn't assume we have the expertise to figure it out so easily or have the time to spend in debugging your code.

Comment: But what do you want to turn a `'na'` into?  Leave it as `'na'`?  Or return `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are happy to replace the value `'na'` with `None`, or more generally, any non-float looking text with `None`, then you could do something like:

```
def converter(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None

alist = [converter(x) for x in alist]
```

This will convert anything to float that it can.  So, as it stands, this will also convert existing numbers to float:

```
>>> [converter(x) for x in ('1.1', 2, 'na')]
[1.1, 2.0, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

When python lists, sets, dicts, etc are printed out, they are printed in the same format that python uses to compile the "raw code." Python compiles lists in quotes. So you just need to iterate over the list.

Simply use a generator expression to fix this (though it really doens't have much effect unless you are displaying on a tkinter widget or something):

```
>>> alist = ['4', '1.6', 'na', '2e-6', '42']    

>>> for a in alist:
...    print(a)

>>> 4
>>> 1.6
>>> na
>>> 2e-6
>>> 42
```

I'm not sure where the "na", "nan" confusion is coming from. Regardless, if you want to lose the quotes, run your code through a generator expression and it will no longer be under the "list class" - hence, the quotes will no longer appear.

The list elements are all still the same type,

edit: clarity, grammar